# Linux, reading the tape device

Tags: c, linux

I'm using plain C and trying to read data from stream device (single tape)

```
size_t res=0;
size_t total=0;
char data[512];
FILE *f = fopen("/dev/st0","r");
if(!f)
{
    perror ("Error:");
    printf( "Value: %d\n", errno );
    return;
}
while((res=fread(data,1, sizeof data,f))>0)
{
    total+=res;
}
fclose(f);
printf("read: %ld bytes\n", total);
```

It doesn't work this way, so I assume there should be some specific way to do it.
I didn't find something useful in google. May be source code of mt tool can help, but again it doesn't read/write to tape.

The result is
read: 0 bytes

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen`.

Comment: What is this code exactly supposed to do?

Comment: Does it work if you do `cat /dev/st0 > myfile`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated the post.

Comment: Yes, it works for cat and doesn't work for dd. As expected

Answer (score 3):

To read the first `sizeof(data)` bytes (if any) from the device specified do like so:

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE /* for ferror */

#include <stdio.h>

#define DEVICENAME "/dev/st0"

int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */

  size_t total = 0;
  char data[1024];

  FILE * f = fopen(DEVICENAME, "r");
  if (NULL == f)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s'.\n", DEVICENAME);
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else 
  {
    total = fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), f);
    if (ferror(f))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from '%s'.\n", DEVICENAME);
      result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    }  

    fclose(f);
  }

  printf("Read %zd bytes from '%s'.\n", total, DEVICENAME);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: No, removed. @Shahbaz

Comment: Probably a habbit when writing macros to carry the box with extra parenthesis along. @Shahbaz

Comment: I think you mean `if(NULL == f)`, it isn't going to compile with only a single `=`.

Comment: @Kninnug: That's why I put the `NULL` first. Thanks for taking over the compiler's part ... ;-)

Comment: Yep, +1 for using [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). That would have been an annoying bug otherwise.

Comment: Ok, now I got  Error reading form '/dev/st0'.
Read 0 bytes from '/dev/st0'.

Comment: Tape should be considered a hybrid of a block and char device.  The device must read whole blocks at a time (like HDD/SSD), but the size of the blocks can vary from block-to-block.  Depending on the tape drive, you can usually set it to variable block mode (set block size = 0) and do a read with a sufficiently large buffer to get a single block.  If all the blocks are the same size, you can set the drive to that size and read multiple blocks with a single read operation (for better read/write performance).